# Print a web page without cuting a div

Tags: html, css, printing

I am looking for a way to print some multiple div ( the same div with different content ). But I don't want that the page cut a div in two A4 pages.
Good example :

```
PAGE 1
[DIV]

[END-DIV]

[DIV]

[END-DIV]
PAGE 2
[DIV]

[END-DIV]
```

But I don't want to have thing like that :

```
PAGE 1
[DIV]

[END-DIV]

[DIV]
**PAGE 2**
[END-DIV]

[DIV]

[END-DIV]
```

Is there a way to do that ?  The only code I saw was :
 `<DIV STYLE="page-break-before:always"></DIV>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use CSS properties `page-break-inside` and/or `page-break-after` and/or `page-break-before`:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp
and I guess for your needs it's fine to use `page-break-inside` only:

HTML:

```
<div class="dont-break-me"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.dont-break-me{
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```